# Azure AD Premium to Basic

Tags: azure-active-directory

We currently signed up for Azure AD Premium subscription specifically for allowing self service password management for our O365 users.  Upon evaluation it appears AD Basic subscription may be better suited for our needs.  Does anyone have information about converting the subscription from Premium to Basic?

Thanks,
-Tony V

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply add the subscription to AAD Basic, re-license your users (e.g. using AAD PowerShell), and then cancel the AAD Premium subscription.